# Why did Teracopy show 100% progress so early?

Tags: windows-10, usb, usb-flash-drive, cd, teracopy

I am trying to copy data from CD to my pen drive using Teracopy (software).

[image]

Even with data still **left** to copy, it started showing **100%**. Why so?

Comment: You would have to ask the author of Teracopy this question.  It is closed source.  This looks like a math bug to me but there is no way for me to know without looking at the source code.  Have you considered [filing a ticket](https://help.codesector.com/communities/1-teracopy-for-windows) and see if the author answers you?

Comment: It looks like I was correct.  There are bugs in AT LEAST [the estimates of progress](https://help.codesector.com/en/communities/1/topics/2185-teracopy-overestimates-numbers-billions-of-seconds-millions-of).